# ssh does not terminate on fatal error

Tags: systemd, sshd

I have a custom sshd service started with ssytemd. It's service file is basically the same as the default `openssh-server` service file, but specifies a custom `sshd_config` file which has a custom port and a few other non-standard settings.

Every now and again, someone the `/run/sshd` directory is deleted on the system. This causes all subsequent connections to this SSHD to fail with `fatal: Missing priviledge separation directory: /run/sshd`.

1. What is causing this message?
2. Why isn't a fatal error like this causing the SSHD pid to die? Without the process dying, systemd doesn't know that it has to restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

`sshd.service` on my system has this:

```
[Service]
...
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
```

`RuntimeDirectory` is one of the many sandboxing features of systemd. See `man systyemd.exec` for details.
When your service starts, it will ensure that `/run/sshd` is created with permission 0755.  However it will also be removed when the unit is stopped.

Trouble can happen if two services depend on the same `RuntimeDirectory=`.   Let's say you are happily running and then another unit starts with the same `RuntimeDirectory=` configured.   When that second unit starts, all files become recursively `chown`'d to that unit's `User=` and `Group=`.  When that unit stops, the `RuntimeDirectory=` will be removed.  Either of these actions could really hurt your service.

To protect yourself from that, you have two options:

1. Look for other units that use the same `RuntimeDirectory=`.  It's almost certainly the original `sshd.service` that you have copied.  Then ensure your unit `Conflicts=` with it.  This will prevent both services from being active at the same time and competing.  If you don't want to `Conflict=`, then you could also `systemctl mask` that other service to ensure it never runs.

```
[Unit]
...
Conflicts=sshd.service
```

2. Change `RuntimeDirectory=` to a directory that is unique to your service.

Your second question is a bit tougher for me to answer.  The decision for a fatal error to NOT close the main PID is a design decision (or a bug) in sshd.  A quick look in `man sshd` and `man sshd_config` doesn't help me find any options for "abort-on-fatal" or anything like that.

Comment: Hum... RuntimeDirectory does not appear to be related to the privilege separation directory. I specified a custom RuntimeDirectory in service file, made sure that directory existed, but on service restart, I still got the same missing privilege separation directory /run/sshd

Comment: It could be that `sshd` is hard-coding `/run/sshd` instead of using `$RUNTIME_DIRECTORY`.  In that case option2 above is inappropriate.  You should instead of option 1 above.